# How do I create a div element in AngularJs?

Tags: html, angularjs

How do I create a `div` element dynamically in AngularJS?

Example :

```
<table ng-controller="tableController">
 <tr ng-repeat="totaldivs in parameters">
    <td ng-repeat="divId in totaldivs">
    <!-- 
    want to replace something like below div
    <div id="days_01"><span>DIV_01</span></div>
     -->
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In jQuery we can do it using `$('#IdOr.Class').html(param);` How to do it using **AngularJs** ?

Comment: why can't you just put it there `<td ng-repeat="divId in totaldivs"><div id="days_01"><span>DIV_01</span></div></div>`?

Comment: I need to look at the url parameter something like `index.php/?items=10&name='abc'&adr='address'` then I need to append 10 rows with relevant parameters with new div /span etc

Comment: you don't usually create DOM elements manually, the framework does it for based on the template you specified. So just put correct information in the template

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
<table ng-controller="tableController">
 <tr ng-repeat="totaldivs in parameters">
    <td ng-repeat="divId in totaldivs">
       <div id="{{divId}}"><span>{{divContent}}</span></div>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

You're already inside a repeat loop, so the div will be created for each `td`. You just need to bind values to the divs.